# AndEngine Box2d game

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm developing a 2d survival shooter using Box2d extension and I've got some questions:

1. I have two AnalogOnScreenControls. Their listeners modify both
   sprites and bodies. I receive `TouchEventPool was exhausted` and as
   their number grows the game crashes accidently. I've tried to put
   the modification of the bodies and sprites on the UpdateThread but
   that does not solve the problem. What could be the cause?
2. I have a class that at the beginnig of the game loads all the
   textures. After I relaunch the game activity several times I receive
   `Unable to find Phys Addr for` and "green color" interface. But that
   doesn't happen if I clear the memory manually through the Task
   Manager before relaunch What could be the cause? I unload my atlas
   at the end of the game.
3. The game sometimes crashes at start with NullPointerException in
   onResumeGame. The solution suggested is to set
   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" but my device is API
   10 so it doesn't have screenSize property and orientation only does
   not seem to help, because the game starts in portrait mode at times
   (though landscape is set in the code)

Comment: Hi , How did you solved this issue ,I am facing similar one now,, please  help...

Comment: It seems that these kind of problems depend on the device you use, so there is no actully programmatical solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `TouchEventPool was exhausted` this is perfectly normal, don't worry about it. AndEngine allocates touch events when needed. This should not happen all the time though. Make sure you are not "saving" the events into some array or something like that.
2. You probably load your textures over and over again. It's impossible to tell, but I guess your activity is not destroyed (e.g. when you press home) and when you relaunch the game, textures are loaded again.
3. This is probably a bug in your code :)

Comment: 'Slightly' later than expected :D, but still great thanks!